How to pass Struct to React Reducer through Dispatch Payload
Relatively new to React. I am trying to build a login function for a web app. (In React)  I want to require a user to login before having access to internal pages and functions. (As that user data will be linked to what they do, see, etc...)
I want to setup "user" as a global struct/object I can refer to for various functions - and on login, pass the "user data" - (a struct I have set manually now for testing - but will eventually be returned from the login api) to the dispatch, which should update the "user state" with all pertinent information. When I do - I receive the following error:
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {esid, uuid, status...

The error is happening in AuthProvider.(Code listed last) To be complete though, here is the code that gets there, as I suspect that it may be influencing this error(?):
In the App.js, I have an  wrapper around the pages... with a  around the pages that require login.
NOTE: For testing, I am using a "FakeUser". This will be replaced when I integrate the API for login credential verification.
Full code:
App.js
export default function App() {
  return (
<div className="App">
  <AuthProvider>
    <LocationsProvider>
      <StoriesProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route index element={<Login />} />

            <Route
              path="/"
              element={
                <ProtectedRoute>
                  <Route path="home" element={<Homepage />} />
                  <Route path="locations" element={<Locations />} />
                  <Route path="locations/:id" element={<LocationEdit />} />
                  <Route path="locationnew" element={<LocationNew />} />
                  <Route path="memories" element={<Memories />} />
                  <Route path="connections" element={<Connections />} />
                  <Route path="story" element={<Story />} />
                </ProtectedRoute>
              }
            ></Route>

            <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </StoriesProvider>
    </LocationsProvider>
  </AuthProvider>
</div>

Protected Route
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext";

function ProtectedRoute({ children }) {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(
    function () {
      if (!isAuthenticated) navigate("/");
    },
    [isAuthenticated, navigate]
  );

  return isAuthenticated ? children : null;
}

export default ProtectedRoute;

Login Code
export default function Login() {
  // PRE-FILL FOR DEV PURPOSES
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("test@emaildomain.com");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("myfakepassword");
  const { login, isAuthenticated } = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Logging in...");
    if (email && password) login(email, password);
  }

  useEffect(
    function () {
      if (isAuthenticated) navigate("/home", { replace: true });
    },
    [isAuthenticated]
  );

  return (
    <main className={styles.login}>
      <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className={styles.row}>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email address</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            value={email}
          />
        </div>

        <div className={styles.row}>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            value={password}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <Button type="primary">Login</Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}

AuthProvider:
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
const AuthContext = createContext();

const initialState = {
  user: null,
  isAuthenticated: false,
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "login":
      return { ...state, user: action.payload, isAuthenticated: true };
    case "logout":
      return { ...state, user: null, isAuthenticated: false };
    default:
      throw new Error("Unknown action");
  }
}

const FAKE_USER = {
  esid: "1",
  uuid: "11111111-0000-2222-3333333333333333",
  status: "1",
  firstName: "Test",
  lastName: "User",
  screenname: "TestUser01",
  profilepic: "avatar.jpg",
  email: "test@emaildomain.com",
};

function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [{ user, isAuthenticated }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    initialState
  );

  function login(email, password) {
    console.log(FAKE_USER);
    //API Connectivity and verification will go here...
    //payload is causing ERROR

    if (email === "test@emaildomain.com" && password === "myfakepassword")
      dispatch({ type: "login", payload: FAKE_USER });
  }

  function logout() {
    dispatch({ type: "logout" });
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, isAuthenticated, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useAuth() {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (context === undefined)
    throw new Error("AuthContext was used outside AuthProvider");
  return context;
}

export { AuthProvider, useAuth };


The Answer was - - This code was functional. The user data that was causing the error was being output on a different page 
<div>{user}</div>

However, this component was buried and the error was not listing this page name in the error.
it needed to be:
<div>{user.firstname}</div>

Adjusting that code fixed it.  Note to others: sometimes you have to dig deep in nested files... (Mad at myself)
